# How can I determine when the form data has been successfully entered in the database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

**First here is my code:**

```
<?php 
//establish connection to the database
require("database.php");
try{
  // prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO clients (phonenumber, firstname) VALUES (:phonenumber, :firstname)");
$stmt->bindParam(':phonenumber', $phonenumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);

 // set parameters and execute
if(isset($_POST['phonenumber'])){ $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber']; }
if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){ $firstname = $_POST['firstname']; }
$stmt->execute();

}catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Could not insert data into the database $e";
        exit;
        }
//my attempt on checking if the data has been successfully entered in the database
        $inserted = true;
?>

<h2>The Form</h2>
<hr />
<br />
<form action="" method="post">
Number: <input type="text" name="phonenumber" value="" />
<br /><br />
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br />
<hr />

</body>
</html>
```

**Then I'm attempting to check if the form data has been successfully entered like this:**

```
<?php 
if($inserted = true){ 
echo "THE DATA HAS BEEN SUCCESSFULLY ENTERED IN THE DATABASE"; 
}
?>
```

Now as you can see I'm trying to set a variable named $inserted as true when the data is entered so that I can determine if the data has been entered successfully. But for some reason it is NOT working. It keeps giving me an error that `$inserted` is undefined so I wrapped it with `isset()` and even though that got rid of the error it however did not check to see if `$inserted` was set. In other words I always keep getting the echo message that it has been entered successfully even though it has not for some reason.

Help is greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: `$stmt->execute();` will return a boolean value. Check to see if it's true or false.

Comment: why not just use [`->lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) then you'll know its inserted

Comment: Ok but how would I check if `$stmt->execute();` is true or false? @David

Comment: `if($stmt->execute()) { true } else { false }`

Comment: @David that would give me a Fatal Error... Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Comment: @Ghost well how would I use that in an if statement outside of the try catch block like in my example

Comment: a simple if statement would suffice, just check if its greater than zero, of course test this condition after the execution was made

Comment: use mysql_insert_id();

Comment: @Ghost that would give me a fatal error... Fatal error: Call to a member function lastInsertId() on a non-object

Comment: @satishrajak how would you use that in an if statement outside of the try catch block?

Comment: $last_id=mysql_insert_id();if($last_id>0){echo 'success'}else{'error'};

Comment: Have you set PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION for your connection?

Comment: @satishrajak No luck gave me this error: Deprecated: mysql_insert_id(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: @MarkBaker yes I have `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` set when I establish my connection in database.php

Comment: use $lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId();

Comment: Before any if that if you are getting errors such as "cannot perform [whateverfunction] on non-object" it means you haven't connected correctly to the database or something in your query was incorrect. If you think you are connected, try running var_dump($conn->errorInfo()); through your code.

Comment: Oh no I am 100% sure that I am connected. I have entered multiple data in my database. @Lucas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a flag, you could use the `->lastInsertId` method to check whether the last insertion was succesful.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['phonenumber'])) {
    require('database.php');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];

    try{
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO clients (phonenumber, firstname) VALUES (:phonenumber, :firstname)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':phonenumber', $phonenumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Could not insert data into the database $e";
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    if($conn->lastInsertId() > 0) {
        echo 'insertion was made';
    }

}
?>

<h2>The Form</h2>
<hr />
<br />
<form action="" method="post">
Number: <input type="text" name="phonenumber" value="" />
<br /><br />
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br />
<hr />

</body>
</html>
```

Sidenote: You could also use `->rowCount()` as well:

```
if($conn->rowCount() > 0) {
    // do your thing
}
```

Comment: It worked! very nice Ghost really appreciate it! I put it through many tests and built out what I actually wanted using that.

Comment: Oh and by the way I didn't need `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` I already had that in my database.php

Comment: @LucasSantos oh okay, i just thought to add it just in case, sure im glad i was able to help